# Resubmit an app to Google Play

Tags: google-play

I'm trying to resubmit an app to Google Play, but I can seem to find a way, technically to do so.

I have answered yes to "Is your app primarily directed towards children under the age of 13 as defined by COPPA?", and then there are different things to edit in different pages.

The problem is that there isn't a save button, only "RESUBMIT APP". So when I'm navigating between the different pages, I cannot find a way to save the changes:

> Google Play listing has been modified. Do you want to leave without saving?

Resubmit app button doesn't work as well, as there are still errors.

I need to update the privacy policy url, content rating and check the "Designed for Families" checkbox.

Did anyone encounter something similar and knows how it can be resolved?

Comment: Yes, I've also contacted them a few days ago, didn't get a reply yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solutions to this Problem.

Steps to follow

1. Under Pricing and Distribution, check "**No**" to "**Primarily Child-Directed**" and click on "RESUBMIT APP".
2. Then go to "**Store listing**" and give your privacy and policy URL and click on "RESUBMIT APP".
3. Now go to Pricing and Distribution, check "**Yes**" to "Primarily Child-Directed".
4. Click on "**Opt in to Designed"** for Families" and click on "RESUBMIT APP".
5. Now you are good to go.
6. App will be published within an hour.

Comment: My app was rejected so I made updates and then I'm doing these steps (although mine is not directed at kids).  After clicking "Resubmit App", I get an alert saying "App Saved".  But I still have the warning flags within the dashboard saying "App rejected", I dont know if this is from the previous rejection or not.  It's confusing

Comment: FYI -  the console interface has changed a bit since this question was asked

Comment: @conor909  How did you fix this problem ?

Comment: @OsamahM I called support. It’s just bad UX, the message updates after it’s been reviewed again. You just have to be patient

Comment: Thanks, so confusing. My app was rejected (Google will not provide specifics as to why, which, you would think they would know why they rejected it!). I'm going to make multiple changes and was worried there is no Save, only Resubmit!

Comment: Cant find any resubmit app option, rejection email says it is there.

Answer (score 16):

A possible way to resubmit a rejected update

• Sign in at Google Play Console.

• Select your app for resubmission.

• Go to "Store presence" > "Main store listing".

• Make a minor change at the store listing to activate "Save" button. For example, add a space after app title or description.

• Click "Save" (after saving you may undo your minor change and click "Save" button again).

• Go to the rejected update and click "Send for review" button.

Done.

Comment: My god how can their "new" Play Console UI be such an utter monumental failure of UX?

Adding a space onto the name in order to "reveal" the unbelievably well hidden "submit for review" button. Total facepalm moment.

Comment: @Jammer , looks like a puzzle to avoid undesirable resubmissions :)

Comment: @Jammer , agree. Moreover similar steps had been provided by official support team for resubmission in my case. After that this answer has been created :)

Comment: @Emil this way useful when the update rejected by reasons related with store listing, some policy violations or even online app content. For example the app may load invalid content (or show advertising for 18+ auditory in 5+ app), in this case Google may decline an update as invalid bundle. But sometimes it is possible to fix content (or to setup advertising into online dashboard) without uploading of a new version of the app and then to resubmit by this steps.

Answer (score 6):

Go to "Store listing" and click on "RESUBMIT APP"
Now "RESUBMIT APP", will be disabled and grey.

There will be questions asked such as price, does app contains ads or not, so select yes if you previously selected no and vice versa, now that resubmit button would be blue, and then change back to the original settings of yes or no and click on resubmit app.

It will show rejected on the dashboard, but on clicking on app, you will see status of processing under rejected, confirming that app has been resubmitted.

Comment: Worked for me. I 've made a small edit on the description of the listing and then the button turned to blue and I was able to resubmit the app.

Comment: Resubmit app is there no more, the rejection email says it is. Nice work confusing people.

Comment: really helpful!Thank you

Answer (score 6):

As of 10/1/2020, it would appear access to the Resubmit App action is managed via the `Publishing Overview > Managed Publishing` Status option which is set to "automatic" by default.

My understanding is that the "automatic" setting will *automatically* resubmit any updates.

I had an app get flagged and, even after the *automatic* update/resubmit I was still seeing all the flag warning messages. Very confusing IMO.

Comment: I updated the information and just waited. There was just no indication of my having completed all requirements on my end; the flag/warning being shown until it was resolved on Google's end.

Answer (score 4):

Our app got rejected due to misleading claims policy then I fixed that issue and few minutes later automatically got this " Update in Review" card in app dashboard.

[image]

Next day app is successfully released. Make sure this publishing status automatic

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Today the only way is generate a new `App Bundle` updating the `versionCode` and upload it again.

Answer (score 1):

On the left pane, scroll up to `Publishing Overview` [here](https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers/8958021446850963732/app/4972644210110030196/publishing). Then click on `Send for review`. Make sure you have fixed the issues sent to you by mail.